# Tabs content is not shown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm newbie in web dev.

I inherited some web project that includes bootstrap, and jquery 1.10.2 (saw in _layout.xml) - not really aware of what is going back-stage (when jquery is used, when bootstrap but never mind)

My goal is to activate tabs view that suppose to be (and wasn't working). I've played a bit with the code below, but I get all the 2 tabs content on the same page, and nothing really happens when pressing the other tab ("reviews"). 
How can I fix that and how this mechanism works (I set id attributes to have the {tab-> content} match and it didn't help :(

```
<section class="site-tabs">
                        <nav class="tabs-nav clearfix">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#about1" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>                              
                                <li><a href="#review1" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                        <section class="tabs">
                            <section class="tab" id="about1">
                                <section class="about">
                                    <p><span>Myself</span>Some Text here.</p>
                                </section>

                            </section>
                            <section class="tab reviews-tab" id="review1">
                                <h3><a href="#">+ Add Review</a></h3>                              
                                </section>

                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </section>
```

Is there need to attach the relevant .css here?

Update :  element :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <title>SiteNAme</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Images/SiteName/userImageLarge.pngfavicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropkick.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autosize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.raty.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
                filter: none;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Could you add your html <head> to your question? I am wondering if you are calling the relevant files.

Comment: attached in the question body

Comment: anyone? someone has any idea here?